# How to declare day?

Tags: c++

How do I declare the day in my code? Not only Sunday, but other days too.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int temperature;
  char day = SUNDAY;

  cout << "Enter your body temperature:" << endl ;
  cin >> temperature ;

  cout << "Enter what day:" << endl ;
  cin >> day ;

  if ((temperature > 40 ) && (day == SUNDAY))
      cout << "Take sick certificate" << endl ;
  else if (temperature > 40 )
      cout << "Do a light work" << endl ;
  else if (temperature > 50 )
      cout << "Go to hospital!" << endl ; 
  else
      cout << "Go to work" << endl ;

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Forgotten homework tag perhaps?

Comment: no,this just try and error form myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare day? You will need a `std::string`. I think you want something like this:

```
#include <string>
....
std::string day = "SUNDAY";
....
if ((temperature > 40 ) && (day == "SUNDAY"))
```

Comment: ok its better that before,

Comment: how i want to put other day,or keep repeat that step?

Comment: With a loop, refer to your book